# Jython syntax error on 'finally' word

Tags: python, exception, jython, grinder

Here's a snippet which causes an error:

```
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('C:\\grinder-3.7.1\\lib
\\.\\nb-romg-file-store\\current\\grinder_test.py', 131, 9, '        finally:'))
```

```
    ss = ''
    self._suggestionLock.acquire()
    try:
        ss = suggestion_strings.next()
    except StopIteration:
        suggestion_strings = suggestions_generator()
        ss = suggestion_strings.next()
    finally:
        self._suggestionLock.release()
```

What may be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Jython 2.4? try/except/finally was introduced in Python 2.5.

Comment: You can nest a try/except block in a try/finally block.

Comment: I am facing this problem even in Jython2.7 . Any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

The Jython you have only supports Python 2.4; `try ... except ... finally` was added in 2.5.